# ROS Answers SE migration: amcl question

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I am new to ROS and I have a question about amcl package. Does AMCL take dynamic obstacles into account? or is it for static obstacles only?

Thanks for your help,
Firat

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59311/amcl-question/) by [frt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4535/frt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL does not try to model dynamic obstacles. However, probabilistic methods like AMCL are generally fairly robust to things like dynamic obstacles, as long as they don't comprise most of your sensor data. For instance, a person walking by the robot while it navigates down a hallway is unlikely to cause to lose localization -- whereas several people circling around the robot and blocking out the laser's view of the walls around it may very well cause it to lose localization.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1